# Check if one promise failed using Promise.all() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm new in promises and I'm currently trying to understand it. As I knew, Promise.all() has no function to check if one of the promises are rejected. So what I've tried is:

```
if ( Promise.all( promises ) ) {
    console.log( "Everything is resolves!" );
} else {
    console.log( "There is a rejected one!" )
}
```

But this seems to be not working. Is there any simple way to check this? I've found some questions with maps and tried it out but it looks wrong for my implementation.

Comment: Promise.all returns a promise, which is truth-y. You catch an error the same way as any other promise; `.catch`. You can also use try and catch with async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `.catch` on the Promise call to see if at least one Promise rejects:

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // At least one of the Promises rejected (or an error was thrown inside the `.then`)
  });
```

Comment: if you instead use `.then(onFullfilled, onRejected)` then you can be sure the error is (the first) rejection from the array of promises :p

Comment: Yep, ff course you *can*, it's just usually not a good idea, as I'm sure you know

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I use `.then(fn1, fn2)` **often** - when it's the correct thing to do - hell, half my promise code is `.then(undefined, fn)` because I started using promises before `.catch` was a thing and can't be bothered changing it :p

Comment: It's still not working how it should. It looks like the post function is not wrapped correctly. Not sure how to fix this..

Comment: @Mr.Jo Can you explain the problem in more detail? Are you sure that `promises` is an array of Promises?

Answer (score 1):

Promises.all( [promises array] ).then(function).catch(errorfunction)

you can do like this:

```
Promise.all([promises array])
.then((promisevalue) => console.log('returned'))
.catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all